# Text overflowing that has the Bootstrap class: form-control

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

My text is overflowing within a `span` element which has the class: `form-control`

Code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <label>Notes:</label>
    <span class="form-control"><%= @stuff.notes %></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And when `@stuff.notes` has a lot of text, it overflows like this:

[image: Image of text overflowing]

I did look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153092/bootstrap-inline-form-controls-all-wrap-at-the-same-time-as-their-container-gets), as well as [this ticket within bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17691).  I am still having trouble coming up with a solution.

**Update:**

I realized I could use a form helper (even though it isn't a form) like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <label>Notes:</label>
    <%= text_area_tag :notes, @complaint.notes, {class: "form-control", disabled: "disabled"} %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which renders it like this:

[image]

But I don't like how the disabled html attribute grays out the box and mutes the text.  It makes it difficult for the user to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a basic panel to get a similar feel. See [Bootply Here](http://www.bootply.com/TfNPMe5RNP)

```
<label>Notes:</label>
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    Basic panel example
  </div>
</div>
```

And if you really want to match the look of the `form-control` class, you could add a custom `.inset-box-shadow` class which would override the box shadow on the panel and give it that formy look. That may confuse users though, they may want to click and type in it.